# How to print a http request as a string in java

Tags: java, android

This is my code which is used connected to URL,its working fine but i want http request in string, , I want know what is actually being sent to the servers

```
HttpURLConnection conn = null;
                try {
                URL url = new URI(baseURL).toURL();
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                        "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(builder.toString().length()));
                conn.setConnectTimeout(10000);

                conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
                conn.setUseCaches(false);

                OutputStream outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());`
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
                writer.write(builder.toString());
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
                outputStream.close();
                conn.connect();
                requestStatusCode = conn.getResponseCode();
            }
```

I want what is actually being sent to the servers

Comment: Do you want to check the used URL or all http params ?

Comment: i want check user agent, host and

Comment: how to print a http request as a string, and then provide me with the output

Answer (score 1):

You can print your Header fields using the `getHeaderField(int n)` doc over [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#getRequestMethod()), use it in a loop and you'll get all the header.
an other way to do this would be through an http analyzer like Wireshark.

Answer (score 1):

I thing you need this code:

```
Enumeration<Sting> paramNames =req.getParametersNames(); 
    while(parametersNames.hasMoreElements()) {
    String name = parametersNames.nextElement(); 
    System.out.println(req.getParamter(name);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a proxy instead of print out to view what request is being sent - (there's a good tutorial [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/using-web-debugging-proxies--net-29828)) and what is being sent back from the server.

Also consider using libraries like [Volley](https://github.com/mcxiaoke/android-volley) or [OKHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) for networking, rather than doing it manually - both libraries are widely used and well supported on Stackoverflow etc.